# chrome file upload window in webdriver headless mode

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I'm unable to control chrome file-upload window in selenium, so I use pyautoit, this works fine in desktop mode, but I need it to run in a headless linux container.

Is there any way to control it in headless mode? (its a single page app with a complex upload script I haven't figured out the internal post to work, hoping I can bypass it with selenium).

```
webdriver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//label[@class='button']").click()
time.sleep(2.0)
autoit.win_wait_active("Open", 5)
autoit.send(fname)
autoit.send("{ENTER}")
```

I'm using python 3.10.4, selenium 4.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually Button specified for browsing the file from Local system has the xpath as `//input[@type='file']`

You can use this xpath to send keys the local path

```
webdriver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']").send_keys("Your Local path")
```

For best practice you should store your file to be uploaded in your git repository and provide git clone path/git repository path where your file is located.

The below example in Java.
eg.`System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\"+"src/test/resources/TestData/Input/"+"yourFile"`

Comment: This was brilliant, just had to send the fname, wait some secs, and it showed up, not even press the button. The upload script was just events.